# Convert All PDF pages to single image in java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Convert All PDF pages to single image in java
I'm having a pdf file of having 700KB, i want to convert it into single image with reduced size. I tried it below way.I'm using PDFBox

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(file,null);

List<PDPage> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
int i =0;
for ( PDPage page : pages )     {
        BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage();
        BufferedImage imageBW = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),                                      
image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        Graphics g = imageBW.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        java.io.File file1 = new    
java.io.File(("D:\\FTPUploads\\GuestSupply_"+i+".jpg"));

        ImageIO.write(imageBW, "jpg", file1);
        i++;
    }

But there difference found is only 10 KB and here it created into 2 images (pdf having 2 pages) i need it in single image. Could you please help me out on this.
```

Comment: Can you please provide me some solution

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) is a software suite to create, edit, compose, or convert bitmap images.It have the options to join images .The functionality of ImageMagick is typically utilized from the command line or  [Im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) is a pure-java interface to the ImageMagick command-line.It is distributed under the Apache 2.0 license.

So first convert every PDF page to seperate image using PDFBox and combine all images using ImageMagick.

**Reference :**
  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/